# What determines the output voltage of this SMPS?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, design

This website http://danyk.cz/impulz4_en.html says that the output voltage is due to the zener diode that has a forward voltage drop of 18V. But zener diode is just a clipper that regulates the output voltage so, What is the component that really produce (or specify or determine) the output voltage? Is it the transformer or the IC?

Also, What is the 180V of the transil? Is it the maximum forward voltage or the reverse voltage drop? I think it is the reverse voltage drop due to the diode.

Can I replace BA159 with 1n4007?

Thank you very much,

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The zener DOES control the output voltage - at about 19V across the output terminals, the zener begins to conduct and starts to turn on the the opto-isolator. This in turn signals the TNY267 that the correct level of output voltage has been met and it's time to start backing off dumping too much energy into the transformer.

If loading increases and the output voltage starts to drop the zener reduces its conduction and starts to turn off the opto isolator.

The transil "snubs" out back-emfs from the transformer - it needs to be rated in volts below the level at which the MOSFET in the TNY267 might suffer damage. Given that there could be a DC voltage of 240 x 1.414 volts (339 volts) the MOSFET will be protected to no more than 339V + 180V = 519 volts. Note also that the BA159 prevents it conducting in normal diode mode hence the voltage rating of 180V is the reverse breakdown voltage.

I suspect the BA159 needs to be fast recovery type and the 1N400x series is certainly not that! BA159 is specified as having 500 ns reverse recovery time whereas the 1N4007 is about 30 us. When a diode goes from forward conducting to reverse blocking there is this time that even though the diode is reverse biased it acts as a forward conducting device. Clearly if you are switching at (say) 100 kHz, 500 ns represents 20% of the time that it could be reverse conducting. 30us would be a disaster!

Comment: I'm just 2 minutes late... I guess I was born with these 2 minutes late.

Comment: I'm even later ;-) Well it's not a race to be first. Now we have 3 similar answers so they must be true :-)

Comment: The zener conducts if the voltage (on its ends) is above 18V. ~19V is achieved because IR led in optocoupler have also voltage drop of around 1.5V.

Comment: @Darko I did say 19V across the output terminals and not the zener terminals.

Comment: @Andy Sorry, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 5):

The zener, here, is not used as a "clipper", as you say. In this situation, it is used as kind of voltage reference, used to provide feedback to the TNY267 IC and maintain regulation.

When the voltage on the output rises above the zener voltage, the zener starts to conduct. This allows current to flow through the two resistors (100R and 470R). This creates a voltage difference across the 470R, and, at some point, enough so that the opto diode starts to illuminate. When this happens, the TNY267 sees, through its pin nr 4 (feedback) that the output voltage has reached its target, and adjusts (lowers) the duty cycle so the output voltage does not rise more. On the opposite, when the output voltage drops, the zener stops conducting, which leads to an increase of the duty cycle.

The 180V transil is clamping the voltage across the transformer, and thus limits the voltage also across the internal TNY267 mosfet, in order to protect it. Because the leakage inductance in the transformer leads to rather high voltage spikes when the mosfet switches, so you need some kind of clamping across the primary winding (there are several alternatives, either a zener clamp like here, or a RC snubber, ...).

Although 1N4007 and BA159 have the same reverse voltage rating and current rating, BA159 is fast switching. So it may not be a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

*But zener diode is just a clipper that regulates the output voltage*

In this case it is **not**, it just drops about 18 V. Suppose 100V AC came out of the transformer there would be 18 V across the zener but around 80 V across the 100R and the 470R resistors. There would still be almost 100 V at the output.

The output voltage is regulated by the zener **and** the LED in the optocoupler. Together they will conduct at around 19 V, the LED will illuminate the photo transistor and via the TNY267 provide feedback.

The ZD/transil is a transorb or a high voltage supression diode. When the switch in the TNY267 switches off but there is still magnetic energy inside the transformer, a high voltage is induced at the 140z side of the transformer. The transorb diode clips this to a safe value so the TNY267 is not damaged.

**No** you cannot replace the BA159 with an 1N400x because these are much slower diodes. This circuit switches at a couple of 100 kHz or so. Way too fast for a 1N400x series diode. Only use 1N400x for mains rectifiers at 50 or 60 Hz. Maybe they can handle 1 kHz but I would not go above that.